# Capture/Compare Input Mode is not being triggered by PD12 on STM32F407 Discovery

Tags: stm32, c, timer, input

I am trying to set a pin with capture/compare input mode and I will get the trigger from the PD12 pin which we have a green LED.
When I open the debugging mode, I see no change on the "timestamp" integer that I defined. I couldn't understand the reason.
I also connect PD12 and PB5 with a jumper cable.

First I tried to use the same timer but a different channel. When I saw it is not working(I was using the PD13 pin which we have the orange LED connected here). I decided to change the timer with an empty pin and not used time. However, this is not working, as well.

I write bare-metal code here. Please help me to find my failure.

Code File:

```
#include "stm32f407xx.h"

#define TIM2EN      (1U<<0)
#define TIM3EN      (1U<<1)
#define TIM4EN      (1U<<2)

#define TIM_CEN     (1U<<0)
#define TIM4_OC1M   (1U<<4|1U<<5)
#define TIM4_CC1E   (1U<<0)

#define TIM3_CC2E   (1U<<4)
#define TIM3_CC2S   (1U<<8)

#define RCC_GPIODEN (1U<<3)
#define RCC_GPIOBEN (1U<<1)


void tim2_1Hz_init(void){
    /*Enable the Timer clock*/
    RCC->APB1ENR |= TIM2EN;
    /*Set Prescaler PSC*/
    TIM2->PSC = 16000 - 1;
    /*Set Auto-Reload Register ARR*/
    TIM2->ARR = 1000 - 1;
    /*Set the counter value*/
    TIM2->CNT = 0; // As the default counter is upcounter
    /*Enable the Timer 2 counter*/
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CEN;
}

void tim4_PD12_CCM_init(void){
    //LED GPIOD Clock Configuration
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_GPIODEN;
    //Set the PD12 as OUTPUT
    GPIOD->MODER &=~(1U<<24);
    GPIOD->MODER |= (1U<<25);
    /*AF2 Settings*/
    GPIOD->AFR[1] |= (1U<<17);
    /*Enable the Timer clock*/
    RCC->APB1ENR |= TIM4EN;
    /*Set Prescaler PSC*/
    TIM4->PSC = 16000 - 1;
    /*Set Auto-Reload Register ARR*/
    TIM4->ARR = 1000 - 1;
    /*Set the CC mode as Toggle mode*/
    TIM4->CCMR1 |= TIM4_OC1M;
    /*Enable the CC output register*/
    TIM4->CCER |= TIM4_CC1E;
    /*Set the counter value*/
    TIM4->CNT = 0; // As the default counter is upcounter
    /*Enable the Timer 4 counter*/
    TIM4->CR1 |= TIM_CEN;
}

void tim3_PB5_CCM_init(void){
    //PB5 GPIOB Clock Configuration
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_GPIOBEN;
    //Set the PD12 as OUTPUT
    GPIOB->MODER &=~(1U<<10);
    GPIOB->MODER |= (1U<<11);
    /*AF2 Settings*/
    GPIOB->AFR[0] |= (1U<<21);
    /*Enable the Timer clock*/
    RCC->APB1ENR |= TIM3EN;
    /*Set Prescaler PSC*/
    TIM3->PSC = 1600 - 1;
    /*Set the CC mode as Input mode*/
    TIM3->CCMR1 |= TIM3_CC2S;
    /*Enable the CC output register*/
    TIM3->CCER |= TIM3_CC2E;
    /*Enable the Timer 3 counter*/
    TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CEN;
}

#ifndef TIME_H_
#define TIME_H_


void tim2_1Hz_init(void);
void tim4_PD12_CCM_init(void);
void tim3_PB5_CCM_init(void);
#define TIM3_SR_CC2IF       (1U<<2)

#endif /* TIME_H_ */

/*We'll connect PD12 pint to PB5 pin in this project.*/
/*When PD12 has the rising edge signal, PB5 will be triggered.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f407xx.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "systick.h"
#include "time.h"

int timestamp = 0;

int main(void){
    tim4_PD12_CCM_init();
    tim3_PB5_CCM_init();
    while(1){
        while(!(TIM3->SR & TIM3_SR_CC2IF)){}
        timestamp = TIM3->CCR1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks as if TIM4->CCMR1 isn't correctly configured. Channel 2 should be configured in input capture mode, but is in its default setting (output compare mode). You should set CCMR1_CC1S to 2. For trigger in both edges, set CCER_CC1P and CCER_CC1NP both to 1.

Comment: Your code would be easier to maintain if you didn't define constants like `RCC_GPIODEN`. They already exist and use a naming scheme like `RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN`. And please write `GPIOD->AFR[1] |= (2U<<16)` instead of `GPIOD->AFR[1] |= (1U<<17)` as it better expresses that you want to select mode 2.

Comment: Problem is not on tim4. It is not set as input capture mode.